# Is there a technical reason why there aren’t any basic USB Type-C to USB Type-C multiport hubs?

Tags: usb-c, usb-hub

Not asking for shopping advice, but simply to ask that after spending more time searching for this kind of thing than I expected, it seems the main type of USB Type-C hubs out there translate/convert a USB Type-C connection into multiple USB A female ports.

This makes sense given the overall popularity and prevalence of USB A cables and devices out there currently. But it would seem to me there should be at least some basic USB Type-C to multiple USB Type-C hubs out there. But I can’t find any.

And by USB hub I mean just a hub: I don’t mean one of these dongles that is a veritable “Swiss Army” knife of too many connections—like DVI, USB ports, Ethernet and maybe even an SD card port—but a basic port multiplier.

FWIW, I am asking this because I have a MacBook Air (2018) and for all intents and purposes I don’t need USB A type connections for much of my daily uses. But having at least 1 to 2 more USB Type-C ports would be helpful in some cases.

So is there some kind of host/guest limitation to the USB Type-C spec that prevents this or is it simply a supply and demand sort of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Not asking for shopping advice, but simply to ask that after spending more time searching for this kind of thing than I expected, it seems the main type of USB Type-C hubs out there translate/convert a USB Type-C connection into multiple USB A female ports.

The devices you are finding are designed for products that only have a single Type-C port for whatever reason.  Most USB devices still require a Type-A port on the host.

Having a single Type-C port does not prevent you from using it to its full potential though with cables like [USB Type-C to USB Type-A USB 3.2 Gen 2](https://www.tripplite.com/usb-type-c-male-to-usb-type-a-male-cable-10-gbps-usb-if-certified-3-foot~U428C03G2).  Video passthrough wouldn't be possible with cable for obvious reasons.

> And by USB hub I mean just a hub: I don’t mean one of these dongles that is a veritable “Swiss Army” knife of too many connections—like DVI, USB ports, Ethernet and maybe even an SD card port—but a basic port multiplier.

USB Hubs that only have additional Type-C ports are indeed rare.  [Products](https://www.tripplite.com/7-port-industrial-grade-usb-3.1-gen-2-hub-10-gbps-4-usb-a-3-usb-c-15kv-esd-immunity-metal-housing~U4604A3CIND) that have Type-A and Type-C ports do exist though.  You can also use [adapters](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=35254) to turn the Type-A to Type-C ports.

> FWIW, I am asking this because I have a MacBook Air (2018) and for all intents and purposes I don’t need USB A type connections for much of my daily uses. But having at least 1 to 2 more USB Type-C ports would be helpful in some cases.

You might have to settle on what you can find due to the fact USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 products are going to be released instead of USB 3.2 Gen 2 products. If you need battery charging support be sure to get a USB Hub that specifically provides that support.

> So is there some kind of host/guest limitation to the USB Type-C spec that prevents this or is it simply a supply and demand sort of thing?

I truly believe the limited product selection is due to market demand.

Comment: Since I now have a device that supports USB Type-C, my own answer, is sort of helpful to myself.  I am in it for the speed increases though.

Answer (score 4):

Belkin is selling a product ([USB-C 4-Port Mini Hub](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U090/)) ($49.99) which you may find useful.

It splits one USB-C into:

- 2 x USB-C
- 2 x USB-A

As it is only 1-to-2, I don't know how useful it will be.
Power requirements might be the reason that 1-to-2 is the most you can expect
at the moment.
When such hubs become available they will need to be self-powered,
but nothing like that exists now.

It seems that most manufacturers see this market as more that of docks,
so what you are searching is truly rare.

Comment: What you have to be careful of is the specifications of devices like this.  This particular device has a shared 900mAh charging capability.  You also lose the ability to pass video through the port.  It's also limited to 5 GB/sec (which would make it basically a USB 3.1 Gen 1 hub with Type-C ports)

Comment: Power requirements are a good point. Any such hub would need to be self-powered, and nothing like that exists now. 1-to-2 might be the best you can expect without it.

Comment: @Ramhound I just found a hub that works perfectly for my needs and delivers USB-C 3.1 Gen 2 (10GBps) speed. The [IOGEAR GUH3C22P](https://www.iogear.com/product/GUH3C22P/): Two USB-A and USB-C ports. The USB-A ports are 3.0 but the USB-C ports are 3.1 Gen 2 with power delivery (PD 3.0) pass-through up to 100W (85W max with 15W going to the hub itself). This is exactly what I was looking for for my MacBook Air! Works quite well and speeds from external USB drives are really great!